What is the difference, if any, between runai suspend + runai resume vs. runai delete + clone job via UI?
What is the difference, if any, between runai suspend + runai resume vs. runai delete + clone job via UI?
Both runai suspend and runai delete delete logs and any data saved on the container, so I don't see any difference.

Runai suspend + resume pauses and restarts the job, preserving metadata and settings, while runai delete + clone recreates the job from scratch, potentially leading to different configurations.
Both delete logs and container data, but suspend + resume is more efficient for temporary pauses.
